# Term to describe such conversational phrases

Tags: terminology, colloquialisms, conversational-deletion

Is there a term to describe colloquial, chatty phrases such as:

*Weird, I know.*

*Who knew there was a place called Pikachu.*

*You may be wondering...*

I'm doing a written assignment and I have to explain why I've chosen to write in a certain style. I am writing a blog and therefore want it to sound intimate and casual.

Comment: You could say it's an ***easy-going*** or ***intimate** style*.

Comment: What aspect of the phrases do you want to describe??  They are, to a degree, idioms.  Syntactically, they don't have much in common.

Comment: What's wrong with your own description: *colloquial, chatty phrases*?

Answer (score 0):

The first two examples show conversational deletion

> (It's weird, I know / This was weird, I know etc

//

> They were people (/etc) who knew there was a place called Pikachu.)

Deleting subject and verb leaves **crots**. See [Nordquist's article and links at Grammar.com](http://grammar.about.com/od/c/g/crot.htm).

The third example is an **aposiopesis**

> n:  the leaving of a thought incomplete usually by a sudden breaking
>   off (as in “his behavior was — but I blush to mention that”)

[[M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/aposiopesis)]

[Wikipedia has a reasonable article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aposiopesis) with other examples:

> Aposiopesis (... Classical Greek: ἀποσιώπησις, "becoming silent") is a
>   figure of speech wherein a sentence is deliberately broken off and
>   left unfinished, the ending to be supplied by the imagination, giving
>   an impression of unwillingness or inability to continue. An example
>   would be the threat "Get out, or else—!" This device often portrays
>   its users as overcome with passion (fear, anger, excitement) or
>   modesty. To mark the occurrence of aposiopesis with punctuation, an em
>   dash (—) or an ellipsis (…) may be used....
>
> A biblical example is found in Psalm 27, verse 13.[nb 1] it says:
>   "Unless I had believed I would see the goodness of the Lord in the
>   land of the living …"

Comment: Thanks. I'm sorry I wasn't clear about the 2nd and 3rd example, but the 2nd one was supposed to be a finished statement. E.g. Who knew there were people on Mars!    For the 3rd one I wanted to know if there was a term to describe sentences like: now, you may be wondering, when did this all change? (This way of interacting with the reader and going through their thinking process)

Comment: 'You may be wondering, when did this all change?' / 'You're thinking, how can I help?' / 'He's wishing her Happy Birthday.' are less precise than quote structures, in that the actual words used are not necessarily given, but probably tighter than report structures (He's telling her that her dress is torn.). Perhaps pseudo-quote structures.